# Set Timeout Async Webservice Call?

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous

My Webservice is inheriting from `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol`.

I tried to set the Timeout:

```
service.Timeout = 5000; // 5 secs
```

but nothing happens - neither a TimeoutException nor anything else. Once I tried it without any declarations and it took 190 Secs for a `"Connection Timed Out"`. 190 is strange as I thought, that the Default is 100 Secs.

Anyway, the Timeout Property seems to work on "only" synchronous calls, so in my case I'm not wondering why its not working.

I'm calling the methods asynchronous like that:

```
service.GetInfoCompleted += service_GetInfoCompleted;
service.GetInfoAsync();
```

How could I solve my Problem?

Any Help appreciated!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you calling a synchronous or asynchronous method?

Comment: Edited the Question, hope is clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no "native" way of doing so - I had to implement an own [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).

After the Elapsed time b.e 10 Secs I can call Abort() of the async method call

Comment: I would recommend using [`CancelAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.httpwebclientprotocol.cancelasync.aspx) here instead of `Abort`. Looks like `Abort` cancels only last request, so it doesn't seem right for concurrent calls on your proxy. Haven't tested it, just read `ClientProtocol` code.

Answer (score 0):

Your service.GetInfoAsync() should return [IAsyncResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.aspx) . You can wait for 5 seconds for operation to complete, and if it does not, handle the timeout:

```
var result = service.GetInfoAsync();

if(!result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(5000)){
     // handle timeout
}
```

Comment: If he wanted to wait after issuing the call he could just use synchronous code in the first place.

Comment: Well in my case the `GetInfoAsync()` returns void